# What is the alternative of List.of() in java if I'm using java 8 using STS

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to create one Spring Boot Application through STS4 but while I'm using List.of() it never give any suggestion like this due to which getting {beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException} kind of exception

Comment: `Arrays.asList(T...)`?

Comment: @M.Dudek `Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...)))`, if you care about making it immutable.

Comment: @AndyTurner is there a difference to `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(...))`?

Comment: @eis yes, if you passed in an explicit array (as opposed to varargs) you can reassign the elements of the array, unless you copy it. e.g. `Integer[] arr = {0}; List<Integer> list = Collections.unmodifiableArray(Arrays.asList(arr)); arr[0] = 1;` will change `list` too.

Answer (score 6):

Just bear in mind the following difference:

- `List.of` was introduced with Java 9, and it returns an unmodifiable List. The list returned by the method cannot be resized nor modified, which means, you cannot add, remove or replace any element either on the list or its iterator.
- `Arrays.asList`: This returns instead a not resizable List, which means that you can replace an element of the list but cannot remove or add any element.

With Java 8, the best option to get the same thing as `List.of` is to use the static method `Collections.unmodifiableList`. You can use it just to wrap your list, so every time you try to do any operation on the list or on its iterator (i.e. set, add, remove) an  `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown. Here is an example related to a List of String.

```
List<String> newUnmodList = Collections.unmodifiableList(oldList);
```

Comment: Hi @utkarsh-baranwal, i know this post is quite old. However, if you are satisfied with my answer, how about accepting it? That would be highly appreciated. Thanks.